# Is it possible to JOIN a table on the TOP 1 if there is no unique identifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Example

```
SELECT 
  a.SomethingInCommon, 
  tbl1.Status AS Status1, 
  tbl2.Status AS Status2, 
  tbl3.Status AS Status3
FROM Maintable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable tbl1 ON 
    tbl1.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
               FROM SecondTable SomethingInCommon = a.SomethingInCommon)
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable tbl2 ON 
    tbl2.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
               FROM SecondTable WHERE  SomethingInCommon = a.SomethingInCommon 
               AND ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                              FROM SecondTABLE 
                              WHERE SomethingInCommon = a.SomethingInCommon))
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable tbl3 ON 
    tbl23.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                FROM SecondTable 
                WHERE  SomethingInCommon = a.SomethingInCommon 
                AND ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 2 ID 
                FROM SecondTABLE WHERE SomethingInCommon = a.SomethingInCommon))
```

This query joins SecondTable three times to show a record like

```
SomethingInCommon | Status1 | Status2 | Status 3
```

Is there anyway to accomplish these results if `SecondTable` does not have the unique identifier column (ID) ?

Perhaps maybe creating a temporary unique ID on the fly?

Comment: You should probably use a cte with a row_number instead of that kind of query. Anyway, not clear at all, as you use a TOP 1 without ordering : what's the desired order on SecondTable ? You just assume that your IDs are ordered ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have IDs but know the order you want, you could create artificial IDs using ROW_NUMBER() and then do your TOP 1's off of that.

```
WITH TEMP AS (
    SELECT 3 a, 1 b UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 2)
SELECT A, B, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY B ASC) as RowNumber FROM TEMP

;WITH TEMP AS (
    SELECT 3 a, 1 b UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 2)
SELECT A, B, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A ASC) as RowNumber FROM TEMP
```

Answer (score 1):

As Raphael said in the comment, this can be done with CTE like below

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT M.SomethingInCommon, S.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Partition by S.SomethingInCommon ORDER BY S.ID desc) as rn
FROM Maintable M
LEFT JOIN SecondTable S
on M.SomethingInCommon = S.SomethingInCommon 
)
SELECT cte.SomethingInCommon
     case when rn =1 then cte.ID end as Status1,
     case when rn =2 then cte.ID end as Status2,
     case when rn =3 then cte.ID end as Status3
where rn <=3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top three statuses, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select m.somethingincommon,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as status1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then status end) as status2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then status end) as status3
from maintable m left join
     (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.somethingincommon order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from secondtable
     ) s
     on m.somethingincommon = s.somethingincommon
group by m.somethingincommon;
```

If you prefer, you can do this with multiple joins:

```
with s as (
       select s.*,
              row_number() over (partition by s.somethingincommon order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
       from secondtable
      )
select m.*, s1.status as status, s2.status as status2, s3.status as status3
from maintable m left join
     s s1
     on m.somethingincommon = s1.somethingincommon and 
        s1.seqnum = 1 left join
     s s2
     on m.somethingincommon = s2.somethingincommon and
        s2.seqnum = 2 left join
     s s3
     on m.somethingincommon = s3.somethingincommon and
        s3.seqnum = 3;
```